# У меня на сайте есть подстраницы и по ним надо переключатся на selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

Я автоматизирую odealo.com . Там я перевыставляю закончившиеся офферы. И если их больше 20, то появляются подстраницы. Вот так они выглядят:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И я не знаю как по ним переключатся. Мне надо определиться есть ли они и переключится на следующую если она есть. Я пробовал кликать на кнопку "next", но у меня почему-то получалось, что одна страница перевыставлялась несколько раз. Страница имеет вид игра подкатегория и в ней офферы, поэтому мой скрипт имеет примерно такой вид:

```
for game in games:
    ...
    for cat in categorys:
        ...
        for off in offers:
            ...
```

Также подстраницы можно получить, добавив слеш и цифру к url (https://odealo.com/account/finished-offers/minecraft-hypixel/2), но если ее нет оно вернётся первую.
Я использую selenium python. Заранее спасибо. Извиняюсь за то что информации так мало.

Comment: Если страницы транслируются в URL, то  не вижу проблемы в его динамическом обновлении в цикле. Для каждой игры Вы подставляете в URL имя игры и в цикле (к примеру while пока номер страницы не скатится к единицы - надо добавить переменную) - номер страницы. Тут даже селениум не нужен, request и bs4 достаточно

Comment: Проблема в том, что он не скатывается в 1 , а просто возвращает ее.

Comment: Ну это же тоже можно проверить, проверять текущий `URL` страницы которую вернули, если он не соответствует запрошенной, то идем к следующей игре. `selenium` точно предоставляет такой функционал, по поводу `request` и `bs4` - не уверен. Если подумать, можно другой алгоритм проверки надумать, кнчн)